# Having trouble managing identical microphones in Java for recording

Tags: java, usb, audio-recording, microphone, javasound

I would like to know if it is possible to make the distinction between two identical USB microphones (same vendor, same model, same name) and find a unique identifier for each of them.

What I have tried so far was the `getMixerInfo()` method available for mixers with some variations:

```
    // Setup a Line.Info instance specifically of the TargetDataLine class.
    Line.Info targetDLInfo = new Line.Info(TargetDataLine.class);

    // Get all the mixers from the Java AudioSystem
    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    // Iterate through each mixer and see if it supports TargetDataLine
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {

        // Get a temporary instance of the current mixer
        Mixer currentMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[cnt]);

        if (currentMixer.isLineSupported(targetDLInfo)) {
            // This mixer supports recording 
                System.out.println("MixerInfo: " + mixerInfo[cnt]);
                System.out.println("Current mixer supports recording: \n"
                        + "name: " + currentMixer.getMixerInfo().getName() + "\n"
                        + "vendor: " + currentMixer.getMixerInfo().getVendor() + "\n"
                        + "version: " + currentMixer.getMixerInfo().getVersion() + "\n"
                        + "description: " + currentMixer.getMixerInfo().getDescription() + "\n"
                        + "Source Line Info: " + Arrays.toString(currentMixer.getSourceLineInfo()) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

And for my microphones this outputs:

```
MixerInfo: MicrophoneName [plughw:2,0], version 3.8.0-44-generic
Current mixer supports recording: 
name: MicrophoneName [plughw:2,0]
vendor: ALSA (http://www.alsa-project.org)
version: 3.8.0-44-generic
description: Direct Audio Device: Producer MicrophoneName, USB Audio, USB Audio
Source Line Info: []

MixerInfo: MicrophoneName_1 [plughw:3,0], version 3.8.0-44-generic
Current mixer supports recording: 
name: MicrophoneName_1 [plughw:3,0]
vendor: ALSA (http://www.alsa-project.org)
version: 3.8.0-44-generic
description: Direct Audio Device: Producer MicrophoneName, USB Audio, USB Audio
Source Line Info: []
```

I did not give the actual names for the `MicrophoneName` and the `Producer` for advertising reasons but I hope you can understand. As you can see, having the same name for them automatically changes one name to `MicrophoneName_1`. It happens to be the one that is plugged in last and it does not depend on the USB port either.

I am looking for something unique for each of them, like a MAC address that is different for each device and does not change over time. I will use it to select the desired microphone from a list of such unique identifiers. Is there a way to find this in Java? Or maybe a walkthrough that gives me the possibility to use their uniqueness?